# Ajax.Request with Prototype onComplete causing the request not to happen

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, prototypejs

I am having some problems with Prototype's Ajax.Request, if I do the following, the request won't even be made:

`<input name="Update" onclick="var req = new Ajax.Request('/agent/reports/update_chart', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this.form), onComplete:function(transport) {alert("TEST");}}); return false;" type="button" value="Update" />`

But, if I remove the onComplete, like so, it will make the request:

`<input name="Update" onclick="var req = new Ajax.Request('/agent/reports/update_chart', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this.form)}); return false;" type="button" value="Update" />`

What am I missing here?  I am using Prototype 1.5.0.

Comment: You wouldn't have run into this problem if you were using  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes in the alert("TEST") make an HTML syntax error, you need to use single quotes here

Answer (score 1):

Replace double quotes in your alert statement with single quotes.